# (window).load calculates wrong css

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I want to make splash page, which contains just an image inside a link. This image have to be centered both vertically and horizontally on the window. I am using jQuery to accomplish this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){

    $('#JUPITER').css({
        width: (100) + '%'
    });

    $('#middle').css({
        width: (450) + 'px',
        position:'absolute',
        left: ($(window).width() - $('#middle').outerWidth()) / 2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $('#middle').outerHeight()) / 2
    });

});

    $(window).load(function() {

    $('#JUPITER').css({
        width: (100) + '%'
    });

    $('#middle').css({
        width: (450) + 'px',
        position:'absolute',
        left: ($(window).width() - $('#middle').outerWidth()) / 2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $('#middle').outerHeight()) / 2
    });

});

$(window).resize();
```

`#middle` is the parent placeholder div.
`#JUPITER` is the id of the image.

It works just as I wanted when I am resizing the window.

But it doesn't work the right way when I am reloading the page: the image appears with the correct size in the wrong position.

The attribute "left" always gets the value 8px, no matter how I change the window's size before reloading page. The attribute "top" gets a calculated value, but it´s also not correct(from the center 30px to direction bottom). I can't figure it out why.

Comment: Nitpick: Why duplicate the code, just trigger the resize event on page load.

Comment: You are calling window.resize() outisde the load, so that is being called before the images and content is loaded.

Comment: Try to achieve same effect with css instead of `onload`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to apply the style to #middle

```
 Top:   50%;
 Left:  50%;
 width: 0px;
 Margin-left:  -225px;
 Position:  absolute;
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried it with this CSS, and it works now.